# access JSON results from wordpress database with wpdb

Tags: database, wpdb, json

I have JSON results from Google API added to to wp_options table. At this point I just need to echo the specific elements. Namely, the coordinates. The option_name I have is py_menu_item. One of the option_value element is coords. That is what represents the JSON results. The code below yields this response: `array(o){}`

The code:

```
global $wpdb;
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->wp_options WHERE option_name = py_menu_item", ARRAY_A");
$lat = $myrows->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;    //latitude
$long = $myrows->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;   //longitude 
echo $lat;
echo $long;
var_dump($myrows);
```

I am using this Codex page as a guide: [Class_Reference/wpdb](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

Comment: Coords isn't a column in wp_options, is that maybe the meta_key?

Comment: Coords is an element inside the option_value field. It is an element in my custom row py_menu_item. It is what represents all of the JSON data in the option_value field.

Comment: `$wpdb->wp_options` doesn't exist, should be `$wpdb->options`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use SQL to retrieve values from the option table, use the [options API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API). In addition to avoiding using wrong table names (as was pointed out in the comments) you will most likely get better performance.